# canActivate() route guard returning true but not route not loading

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using a route guard to fetch data from an NgRX store and trigger (if required) an API request to load it from the store, prior to a route resolving. Essentially  we wait for the entity to be defined in the store and for a boolean flag to mark it as finished loading, then the observable emits `true` and the route should resolve.

However, despite the observable in `canActivate()` successfully emitting, the route doesn't load, and I see no reason for this. The stream behaves as expected until that point: first `loaded` is false and the entity `undefined`. Then, once the API call is complete, the entity becomes defined, and finally the `loaded` boolean becomes `true`. The filter then allows us through and the 'load pls' console.log is shown once. At this point, surely the route should now load?

```
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getEntity().pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        console.log('load pls');
        return of(true);
      }),
      catchError(() => of(false)),
    );
  }

  getEntity(): Observable<boolean> {
    return combineLatest([this._store.select(getActiveEntity), this._store.select(getActiveEntityLoaded)]).pipe(
      map(latest => {
        const [entity, loaded] = latest;
        if (!entity) {
          this._store.dispatch(new GetItemRequest());
        }

        return loaded;
      }),
      filter(loaded => loaded),
      take(1),
    );
  }
```

(I realise the boolean `loaded` is rather redundant here, but I can't make this work regardless of that)

Comment: Is it true at the time you request (click link or problematically navigate) navigation?

Comment: is what true? (i pasted the code above slightly wrong, still had a desperate "return of(true)" in there)

Comment: right - so if you follow a router link to it, then it resolves. on hard load of the app straight to that route, it doesn't. the router shouldn't behave like this, surely?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm encountering something similar. Resolves fine when accessing the route directly, but when redirecting to it it's just stuck in a loop of a boolean returning true.

Comment: not really, we ended up doing this slightly differently anyway and the issue went away. i found various bug reports around similar things, i suspect there's a bug in there somewhere, but our doing it differently stopped triggering it. not much help, sorry!

Comment: I have the same problem and adding take(1) to the pipe of canActivate observable helped me.